# How to go about implementing logic for ItemProcessor in Spring Batch project

Tags: spring-batch

I just want to hear suggestions about how to implement the processor step for the following scenario in a Spring Batch project:

I need to synchronize certain fields from two database tables in a database. The source table (table2) needs to be compared with the destination table (table 1). If table 2 has fields with a newer timestamp than table 1, then those fields need to be updated in table1.

I have a result set of objects that each represent a row in a database table that is being passed in to the process method of the ItemProcessor which returns an object from the first table :

```
public ObjectFromTableOne process(ObjectFromTableTwo obj2) throws Exception {
         ObjectFromTableOne obj1 = repository.findById(obj2.getId());
//obj2 is not found in table one
         if(obj1 == null){
             log.warn("No object found for ID number {}: ", obj2.getId());
         }
//when object 2 IS found in table 1, compare the fields and only update when  

    }
```

repository.findById() is a method that searches table 1

Comment: How would you do that *without* Spring Batch? If you can share your solution, I can try to help you implement it with Spring Batch.

Comment: ```
//when object 2 IS found in table 1, compare the fields and perform update
if(obj1.getTimeStamp > obj2.getTimeStamp){
perform swap 
}```

Comment: TO be honest im kind of stuck on the logic here, Can you give insight?